# if the function series is uniformly convergent is it also almost everywhere convergent?

Tags: functions, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Well,I know that if the series is normally or almost everywhere convergent,it's also convergent in measure.I wonder if this kind of connection is in other convergence types.For this particular example I want to know if the function series is uniformly convergent. Is it also almost everywhere convergent?and also is it normally convergent?

Comment: If a series converges uniformly, it converges pointwise, hence also pointwise almost everywhere. For the final question, what is your definition of "normally convergent"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_convergence#Definition

fn function series is normally convergent to f if ||fn-f||->0,when n->∞